# replacing part of the string in python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

I apologize for the inappropriate topic title, but I didn't know how to define it.

I have a string which looks like following:

```
string = 'b<3 and d >4 or 4<=a <20'
```

I would like to change this upper string into the following one:

```
new_string = 'b[n]<3 and d[n] >4 or 4<=a[n] <20'
```

Using the string.replace function appeared to be unsuccessful (for example: string.replace('d','d[n]'), as some other parts of the strings have been modified too (example result: 'b<3 and[n] d[n] >4 or 4<=a <20')).
I was wondering if python's 're' module is the real thing for this job?

I am using python 2.7.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `re.sub`; capturing group and backreference:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\b([a-z])\b', r'\1[n]', 'b<3 and d >4 or 4<=a <20')
'b[n]<3 and d[n] >4 or 4<=a[n] <20'
```

`[a-z]` matches an alphabet characters. `\b` used to make sure the variable name is surrounded by [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html); to make the pattern match only a single-character variable name.

`(...)` is to make the pattern is [captured as a group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) (the 1st group), and can be referenced in the replacement string as `\1`.

**UPDATE**

If you  want to replace any variable name, you may need to check whether the matched part is valid variable. Following example is using [`keyword.iskeyword`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html#keyword.iskeyword) to check whether the matched variable name is not keyword.

```
>>> import re
>>> import keyword
>>>
>>> def replace_var(m):
...     varname = m.group()
...     if keyword.iskeyword(varname) or varname[0].isdigit():
...         return varname
...     return varname + '[n]'
...
>>> re.sub(r'\w+',  replace_var, 'b<3 and d >4 or 4<=a <20')
'b[n]<3 and d[n] >4 or 4<=a[n] <20'
```

NOTE: The replacement can be a function, as shown above; the function get a match object, and the return value of the function is used as a replacement string.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply falsetru.
Would you recommend some beginner friendly tutorial on python's 're' module?
I took a look at the:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html ,
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html ,
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm ,
but all of these are not really beginner friendly ones.

Comment: @marco, Actually https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html was my first exposure to the regular expression.

Comment: @marco, I think experimenting `re.search`, `re.findall`, `re.sub`, ... in Python interactive shell while you are reading the howto documentation is good enough. <--- I did it when I learn regex.

Comment: @marco, If you are not familiar with python interactive shell, using https://regex101.com/#python is another way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply once again falsetru. I am using Notepad++ instead of python interactive shell, and yes, I am not familiar with python interactive shell.